# Access system properties in property file

Tags: java, environment-variables, system-properties

I have set a system property in my java file as :

```
System.setProperty("myRunOnEnv","dev");
```

Now I am using this system property in my .properties file as

```
my.env=${myRunOnEnv}
```

& later in my java code I am getting the value as

```
XYZ.getProperty(...)
```

But the value of the my.env comes out to be "${myRunOnEnv}" instead of "dev". What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, Java just does not have this feature to replace `${...}` by the value of system properties. You'd have to program this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In the properties file give

```
my.env=${sys:myRunOnEnv}
```

Note that you should load the .properties file after setting the System.setProperty

Comment: My `.properties` file is loaded at startup through spring and I've added the property as a `-D` parameter when starting tomcat, but it doesn't work. Any idea what's going wrong ?